# Code Golf: Least Common Multiple

Tags: code-golf

"CodeGolf" challenge:  write the shortest practical Least Common Multiple function that:

1. Does not use built in `GCD`, `LCM` or any related fuctions
2. Accepts multiple arguments in any order, e.g. `LCM[3, 20, 6]`
3. In the spirit of [the original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8540349/618728), obfuscated is better

Comment: There were some discussions in the chat room that felt against code golf questions. Hmm...

Comment: @J.M. I missed them.  If you've got a link I'll read them.

Comment: Apparently, it's in [meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136) already. Never mind, then...

Answer (score 11):

New code, Golfing Simon's method (now v10-syntax compatible):

```
lcm = Fold[#/#2/._~_~x_|_:># x&,1,{##}]&
```

---

This was my original code from a tongue-in-cheek answer on StackOverflow:

```
gcd = If[#2==0,#,#2~#0~Mod@##]&
lcm = Fold[##/gcd@##&,#,{##2}]&
```

As a one-liner:

```
lcm = Fold[If[#2==0,#,#2~#0~Mod@##]&@##^-1##&,#,{##}]&
```

Intentionally obfuscated:

```
lcm = If[{}!={##2},#0[If[#2==0,#,#2~#0~Mod@##]&[#,#2]^-1#*#2,##3],#]&
```

The fact that it throws errors yet works just fine is part of the game.

Comment: Outstanding! It never occurred to me that you could deal with Rationals *and* Integers in a single rule. Brilliant stuff. I had a look to see if I could replace `Fold` with some `#0` trickery, but the code to terminate the recursion is just too big. If only `Fold` was a longer word :-) I think this might just be unbeatable.

Comment: @Simon Thanks. :-)  Using `|` on the LHS of a pattern is one of my favorite "tricks."  I too experimented with using `#0` in place of `Fold`: that is my "Intentionally obfuscated" line at the end of my answer.  By the way, if you use [my `Fold` modification](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5433867/618728) you can knock a couple of characters off of this code.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard While musing these fine examples, I figured I couldn't run the first line of your beautiful solution, as now we have associations and `#x` results in errors. The problem is solved by inserting a space between them.

Comment: @Stitch Thanks; fixed now.

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure how this compares in terms of length but it does not throw errors and isn't even obfuscated:

```
lcm[ls__] := 
 Fold[Denominator[Together[Unique[x]/#1 + Unique[x]/#2]] &, 
  First[{ls}], Rest[{ls}]
```

Just to check it works:

```
f = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 200];

lcm @@ f == LCM @@ f
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  To format your code, select it and click the curly-brackets button above the text box.

Comment: Yes, I did just that but as you beat me to it it wouldn't let me save my edits ;-) Come to think of it, I am not even sure if using addition of fractions violates the condition about not using "related functions"...

Comment: Good enough for me. :-)

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't resist having a go. This is pretty small:

```
lcm = Fold[#(#/#2/.{_~_~x_:>x,_->1})&,1,{##}]&
```

Comment: Marvelous! Just what I was hoping for.  Thanks for playing, Simon.  I do like your style. :-)

Comment: Simon, I Accepted this answer for a short while, but seeing as I was able to shorten it significantly lifted the Accept.  See if you can again beat me.